# Can I make up the word 'proprioceptible'?

Tags: word-usage

Example:

The induced dynamics were **proprioceptible**, the experiencer could feel them physcially manifesting.

I am aware that **propcioceptible** as such is not listed in any of the classical English dictionaries like OED, CED, LED, MW, etc.  but using **proprioceptive**, to me, does not match as well as the suffix '-able/-ible'.

Comment: I don't understand why you say (dictionary-listed) [***proprioceptive***](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/proprioception) "does not match as well as" your (made up) word ***proprioceptible***. As should be obvious, the ***X-able / X-able*** suffix usually conveys something like ***able** [to X / to be X'ed]*, and the full OED definition for ***proprioceptive*** is ***Capable of** responding to stimuli from within the body; of or relating to proprioception*. I suggest you should just use the existing word, not pointlessly coin another.

Comment: The short answer is that, yes, you can make up the word -- but it may not be the best neologism to describe what you want to say, or they may already be a better word that fits.  Why make the reader work to understand you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, no dictionary includes every possible variant of every possible word. They will exclude common morphological derivations a fluent speaker would understand; for example, there are a vast number of words prefixed with *un-* or *anti-* which simply mean the opposite of the root, with no other connotations, and thus no need for a separate entry. This may especially be the case with rare words, of which *proprioceptive* can be counted; you won't find *proprioceptivity* or *proprioceptiveness* in a general purpose dictionary, but you can find plenty of examples in scientific papers.

Second, no one is going to throw you in jail for inventing a word. Plenty of academic and non-academic discourse allows or even requires the use of nonce words and neologisms. Whether or not those words are acceptable to your audience is entirely a function of your audience. If your audience understands what *proprioceptive* means, and has a good understanding of word formation in English, *proprioceptible* seems perfectly reasonable, especially by analogy to *perceptive* and *perceptible*, and compared to derivations using other adjective-forming suffixes (*proprioceptionful*? *proprioceptivous*? *proprioceptivating*?).

Answer (score -1):

## Yes, in the end usage is king

New words are added to English dictionaries all the time, and the way that they choose words is by reviewing journals, newspapers, and other forms of media. If there is what the editors determine to be a "critical mass" of a certain word they add it to the dictionary.

For example, this year Miriam-Webster added "Bioabsorbable" to their dictionary, this is a very similar word to yours in its elements (adding the suffix able/ible to another concept).

Comment: As a general principle I don't think learners / non-native speakers should be encouraged to think "anything goes". They will tend to make "mistakes" that native speakers normally wouldn't, because inevitably they'll be drawing on limited knowledge of how English itself works (and/or including inappropriate principles that apply to their *native* language, but not to English).